# LDAP Filter Syntax Query

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

What would be the syntax for LDAP for the below scenario:

Where sAMAccountName = GRA-* without $. I want the records which are highlighted in green.

[image]

This is my current LADP Filter for your reference:

```
(&(objectClass=user)sAMAccountName=GRA-*))
```

Anyone, Please help with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your filter can work, but you're missing a `(` in front of `sAMAccountName`:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=GRA-*))
```

But you may be able to do better. If those ones that end in `$` are computer objects (which always have `sAMAccountName`s that end in `$`, but also have an `objectClass` of `user`), then you can make sure you only get user objects by including `(objectCategory=person)`:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=GRA-*))
```

If, for whatever reason, those `$` objects are actually user accounts, then you can exclude them with `(!sAMAccountName=*$)`:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=GRA-*)(!sAMAccountName=*$))
```